# How to scale a circle in Libgdx?

Tags: java, libgdx, graphics2d, shape-rendering

On **shapeRenderer**, how to scale a circle? I want to squash it in it's Y axis.

[Example: unscaled circle to scaled circle in it's y axis image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/37oO0.jpg)

Comment: Did you try to draw an [ellipse](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/ci/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/glutils/ShapeRenderer.html#ellipse-float-float-float-float-)?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.